# Castle IoC - do not add interceptor when object injected

Tags: inversion-of-control, interceptor, castle

How can I add interceptor to an interface registration so that it is executed when I call a method from resolved instance (IoC.Resolve) but not when I use an instance that has been injected (as constructor argument) from the inside of my class/object?

In our infrastructure we add an interceptor that opens/closes nhibernate session for every call but then the injected proxy instance will open a session inside of a session and cause deadlocks if you query the same entity in outer and inner session.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at this and I don't see any easy way to change the behavior of the interceptor depending on the context in which it is called.

What you could do is create an interceptor that wraps a component with a singleton lifetime that creates a single session and returns the same session while it is not closed. When trying to create a second session, it returns the initial session and increments a `sessionCreated` counter. When trying to close a session it decrements the `sessionCreated` counter and only closes it if it is 0